# How Do I Stack or Hide my Sidebar on Browser Resize

Tags: css

I'm desperately trying to make my site mobile friendly. To complicate things considerably, while I'm familiar with HTML, I'm also a CSS noob.

I wish to force my floating sidebar to stack for smaller resolutions (iPhone, tablets, etc.). If not, I would be willing to hide the darn thing.

I'm positive that I saw info on how to do this, but can't relocate it by searching *"sidebar stack on browser resize"*, *"hide sidebar on browser resize"* or any variation thereof.

This is a **[test page](http://www.advancedon-site.com/test.html)** I'm using to experiment with.

Comment: Use [`@media` queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). When the document is smaller than `750px` wide:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 750px)  {
  aside { display: none; }
  article { width: 100%; }
}
```

You can also find a list of snippets for standard devices [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful. And timely too.

Comment: Oops! Is this ticket closed? I've found a category of devices that honors the media query's request not to display the aside, but does not increase the article to 100%. I've played with the code, including use of "inherit" for article width, but the only thing that does this is to increase the article's original value under the "main" attribute. And of course that causes other issues. Can you think of anything else I might try?

Comment: It will depend on the context (placement) of your sidebar. A parent could have an overriding style that conflicts with your media query. Or a width of 100% only applies to the container you find yourself in - if that is restricted somehow... YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

If you want mobile friendly UI, you can use Bootstrap's navbar. Here is an [example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/#).